# Typical pyramid pattern in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to print the below pattern in python:

```
       A
      2*2
     B*B*B
    3*3*3*3
   C*C*C*C*C
  4*4*4*4*4*4
 D*D*D*D*D*D*D
5*5*5*5*5*5*5*5
```

```
n=8
k=65
p=1
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i,n):
        print(" ",end="")
    for j in range(i+1):
        if(i%2==0):
            print(chr(k),end=" ")
        else:
            print(p,"*",end="")
    p+=1   
    k+=1 
    print()
```

Comment: Might I suggest `ord('A')` instead of the magic number 65

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use a single loop:

```
n=8
k=65

for i in range(n):
    # decide whether alpha or digit
    c = str(i//2+2) if i%2 else chr(k+i//2)
    # pad with spaces, add repeated character joined with "*"
    print(' '*(n-i-1) + '*'.join([c]*(i+1)))
```

*NB. this only works up to `n=17`, then you'd need to define an additional rule to handle numbers with multiple digits.*

Output:

```
       A
      2*2
     B*B*B
    3*3*3*3
   C*C*C*C*C
  4*4*4*4*4*4
 D*D*D*D*D*D*D
5*5*5*5*5*5*5*5
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Your program is very nearly there: a couple of small changes

Your program is currently outputting this:

```
        A 
       2 *2 *
      C C C 
     4 *4 *4 *4 *
    E E E E E 
   6 *6 *6 *6 *6 *6 *
  G G G G G G G 
 8 *8 *8 *8 *8 *8 *8 *8 *
```

1. You are currently getting spaces after the numbers. This is automatically printed by Python. You can avoid this by converting the number to a string.
2. You are getting an extra `*` at the end of rows. You can fix this by printing the `*` on after each number except the last.
3. The numbers and letters are advancing once on each row, rather than once every two rows

Try this:

```
n=8
k=65
p=1
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i,n):
        print(" ",end="")
    for j in range(i+1):
        if(i%2==0):
            print(chr(k),end="")
            if j<i:
                print("*",end="")
        else:
            print(str(p),end="")
            if j<i:
                print("*",end="")
    if i%2 ==0:
        p+=1 
        k+=1 
    print()
```

Resulting output:

```
        A 
       2*2
      B*B*B 
     3*3*3*3
    C*C*C*C*C 
   4*4*4*4*4*4
  D*D*D*D*D*D*D 
 5*5*5*5*5*5*5*5
```